# Enable some properties in PropertyGrid c#

Tags: c#, properties, windows-forms-designer

I have a working PropertyGrid which in some cases goes disabled.
now I have a new case, in which I need it to enable only one property, is there an easy way of doing it?

thanks

Comment: You can improve question by adding [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling `PropertyGrid`, you could mark all relevant nested properties as `readonly` in your data class, in order to show them disabled in the property grid.

If you want to add ReadOnly attributes at runtime have a look at: https://www.csharp-examples.net/readonly-propertygrid/

Otherwise I'd use a DataGrid or something similar.

Comment: I misunderstood the requirement of OP earlier. Have to edit your question to be able to undo downvote.